# jsTree getting id of the selected node as array

Tags: php, ajax, jstree

I am using jsTree plugin for generating tree menu in my codeigniter web application. My task is to get the id of the selected node and fetch some details sbout the node and display it in the same page. So I used `changed` event of jstree. Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var url="<?php echo base_url();?>";
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#html').jstree({
"check_callback" : true,
'core' : {
'data' : {
"url" : url+"Applications/getfamilytree",
"dataType" : "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
}
},
'plugins' : ['state','changed','wholerow']
}).on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
var id = data.changed.selected;
console.log(id);
callAjax(id);

})

});
function callAjax(id)
{
$.ajax({
url: url+"Applications/populatefamilymenu",
dataType: 'json',
type: 'POST',
data: {id: id},
success: function(data){
console.log(data);
},
error: function(jqXHR, exception){
console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
}
});
}
</script>
```

controller:

```
    public function populatefamilymenu()
{
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$result = $this->Family_model->getfamilyMembersDetails($id);
echo json_encode($result);  
}
```

Model

```
public function getfamilyMembersDetails($id)
{
$this->db->select('*,tab_relations.relation,E2.name AS parentname');
$this->db->from('tab_members');
$this->db->join('tab_relations', 'tab_relations.relation_id = tab_members.relation_id');
$this->db->join('tab_members AS E2', 'E2.member_id = tab_members.parent_id','left outer');
$this->db->where('tab_members.family_id', $id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
}
```

But when I get the id of selected node and pass it to my controller function using ajax, the data returned is showing error:

> Php fatal error: Array to string conversion

When I checked the ajax post error in console its showing:

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT *, `tab_relations`.`relation`, `E2`.`name` AS `parentname`
>   FROM `tab_members`
>   JOIN `tab_relations` ON `tab_relations`.`relation_id` = `tab_members`.`relation_id`
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN `tab_members` AS `E2` ON `E2`.`member_id` = `tab_members`.`parent_id`
>   WHERE `tab_members`.`family_id` = Array
>
> Filename: D:/xampp/htdocs/abc/admin/system/database/DB_driver.php

I used console.log(id) and the result showing :

[image]

I think the array is coming from:

```
var id = data.changed.selected;
```

this is returning an array.So how can I get only the id of the node? Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What does `console.log(id);` give you?

Comment: its showing ["8"]0: "8"length: 1__proto__: Array(0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `data.changed.selected` seems to return an array containing the id as the first element, you need to access the id using:

```
var id = data.changed.selected[0];
```

Now `id` will contain the actual id instead of an array.